# TextBlock in StackPanel in Scrollviewer not showing all content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, size, scrollviewer

I'm reading text from a webservice and want to display all text in the textblock. I'm getting about 50% of the text, and can't figure out why the rest isn't displayed.

Here's my xaml code:

```
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" >

            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/bg-body_mail.png" />
            </Grid.Background>
        <ScrollViewer Name="scrvw">
            <StackPanel Name="stkpnl" >

            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

And here's my c# code :

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {                
            var client = new WebClient();
            string result = "";
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += (q, f) =>
            {
                result = f.Result.Trim();
                string[] strArr = null;
                char[] splitchar = { '~' };
                strArr = result.Split(splitchar);
                pagetitle.Text = strArr[0];


                int lengte = strArr[1].Length;
                int lines = lengte / 40;
                stkpnl.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);



                TextBlock txtVerhaal = new TextBlock();

                txtVerhaal.Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 12, 0);

                txtVerhaal.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

                string text = strArr[1];
                text=text.Replace("<p>", "\r\n\r\n");

                text = text.Replace("<br />", "\r\n");
                text = text.Replace("</p>", "");
                txtVerhaal.Text = text;
                stkpnl.Children.Add(txtVerhaal);


            };
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
```

The total of characters in the result is about 7000 characters, but only about 3000 characters are displayed. There's no limit in any textblock, stackpanel or whatever defined.

I must be doing something wrong, but i can't figure out what.

( Yes, i need that amount of characters in one textblock).

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Please do not create any controls in the code-behind. Describe your view in the **xaml** using `DataTemplate` and provide a `DataContext` that will be visualized in your view. Have you tried to set a breakpoint in your code and to investigate what value the `text` variable is being set to?

Comment: the text variable has the full text from the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

you need to called **layoutupdate();** function after you end the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using WebBrowser control.

var webBroswer = new WebBrowser();
webBroswer.NavigateToString(result);

Then add this browser control 'webBroswer' in your StackPanel 'stkpnl'.
stkpnl.Children.Add(webBroswer);